# read a code file open in netbeans with a plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins

I have a plugin netbenas done , my question is how I can read the contents of a file opened in netbeans ie if I opened a test.java read after the touch of a button located in the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to get the TopComponents from the mode "editor" and search through them for the one with with the name you are looking for. Do a lookup for FileObjects on it (you should get only one),  You can get the text with the asText() function.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    TopComponent tcArray[] = WindowManager.getDefault().findMode("editor").getTopComponents();
    for (TopComponent tc : tcArray) {
        System.out.println("tc = " + tc);

        if (null != tc && null != tc.getDisplayName()
                && tc.getDisplayName().equals("test.java")) {
            Collection<? extends FileObject> fileobjs = tc.getLookup().lookupAll(FileObject.class);
            for (FileObject fo : fileobjs) {
                try {
                    String text = fo.asText();
                    System.out.println("text = " + text);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```